# RequireJs Path and 404 Script

Tags: requirejs

Whats wrong with below code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="js/config" src="require.js"></script>
        <script >
            require(['underscore'],function(_) {
                console.log('Underscore Js Loaded');  
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths:{
        module1:"module1" ,
        underscore:"underscore-min"        
    }
});
```

I am getting 404 Script not found and location of script is set to

```
"{{url}}"js/underscore.js
```

Expected URL should be

```
"{{url}}"js/underscore-min.js
```

Is there anything else to add to config? what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You load `require.js` in the browser
2. RequireJs looks for script with `data-main` attribute
3. Script is found so it requires `js/config` **asynchronously**
4. Next script is trying to require `underscore` module
5. Require is still loading `js/config` so it does not know yet that you want to map `underscore` to `underscore-min`
6. It tries to load regular `underscore.js`
7. Browser fails to load as the response from the server is 404

That is your problem :)

How to fix that?

There are two solutions.

First is to require `underscore` via `deps` and `callback` in the config:

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths:{
        module1:"module1" ,
        underscore:"underscore-min"        
    },
    deps: ['underscore'],
    callback: function (underscore) {
        console.log('Underscore Js Loaded');
    }
});
```

Second is to inline your config in the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="require.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                baseUrl: 'js',
                paths: {
                    module1:"module1" ,
                    underscore:"underscore-min"        
                }
            });
            require(['underscore'],function(_) {
                console.log('Underscore Js Loaded');  
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```